# No module named mediapipe.tasks

Tags: mediapipe

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 3, in <module>
    from mediapipe.tasks import python
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mediapipe.tasks'
```

when I try to run my demo.py which copyed from mediapipe's example, it said "No module named mediapipe.tasks"

how can I fix it?

(I already installed mediapipe at versions: 0.8.9.1)
(I try to install mediapipe by "pip install -q mediapipe==0.10.0", but it said:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mediapipe==0.10.0 (from versions: 0.8.9.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mediapipe==0.10.0)

so I'm confused now, is it bc my mediapipe version wrong so it cant find mediapipe.tasks? If so, how can I install version 0.10.0.
If it's not because my mediapipe version, then how can I fix it?

Plz help, thanks a lot

my pip version is 20.0.2
and my python version is 3.8

I've try to upgrade my mediapipe by:"pip install --upgrade mediapipe"
but it said already up-to-date and have no more effect, the output is as below:

```bash
Requirement already up-to-date: mediapipe in /home/pcai/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (0.8.9.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: matplotlib in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from mediapipe) (3.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: numpy in /home/pcai/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from mediapipe) (1.19.3)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: protobuf>=3.11.4 in /home/pcai/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from mediapipe) (3.20.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: opencv-contrib-python in /home/pcai/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from mediapipe) (4.8.0.74)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: absl-py in /home/pcai/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from mediapipe) (1.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: attrs>=19.1.0 in /home/pcai/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from mediapipe) (23.1.0)
```

Comment: btw, I'm using Linux Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

Comment: Develop on NVIDIA Jetson Xavier NX Developer Kit, this is where I run my Ubuntu system

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/solutions/setup_python#supported_platforms_and_versions), you need to use PIP 20.3 or higher. This is likely why you can't download a newer version of MediaPipe.